# IOS5 Twitter - is there a way to retain the App association?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

If a Tweet is created using the native Twitter API, the Tweet has a "via [my-app]" indication, where [my-app] is a link to the App's home page.

If the same Tweet is created using the new IOS5 Twitter API, the app says "via IOS" and the link points to www.apple.com.

Is there a way to retain my App association when using the IOS5 API without adding a link to the Tweet itself?

If not, can I continue to use the native Twitter API under IOS5 or is this a cause for rejection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `via [my-app]` is set in Twitter application configuration I dont think that you can set it via the iOS Twitter API.

Apple will not reject your app for using the Twitter API directly (for example using Sharekit or MGTwitterEngine). At least they did not reject my app which still uses the ShareKit.

Comment: Isn't it the case that the integration for iOS5 takes care of filling in [my-app] for you when submitted to the store? See https://dev.twitter.com/issues/39 as well. (Apparently your app name shouldn't be known to twitter yet when submitting your app into the store and should less than 32 chars atm.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the FAQ on the Twitter iOS developer site, this only happens because your app is not yet live in the app store:

> **If your application is not yet live in the App Store:**
>
> The application making the requests must be launched in Apple's App Store in order for the
> attribution to display on twitter.com. Note that the iOS5 version of the application must be
> live, not just a previous version.

They also have some tips on how to fix this if it still happens after you're live in the app store here: [https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios-frequently-asked-questions](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios-frequently-asked-questions#Why_is_my_application_attributed_as_from_iOS_instead_of_from_my_application_on_twitter.com)

Comment: Thanks. I guess that by "Note that the iOS5 version of the application must be live, not just a previous version" they mean that if the user has not updated the App, the attribution will not point to me? Not good enough if this is true.